# Restangular getList() returning empty array

Tags: angularjs, rest, restangular

I am trying to invoke a Java REST API from Angular JS using Restangular. I am able to see proper response in the network tab but the response object is having empty array while i try to log the same in console or display in the html file.

```
class TestClass {
/*@ngInject*/
constructor($log, Restangular) {
this.Restangular = Restangular;
this.$log = $log;
this.test = "somethings";
var me = this;
 this.Restangular.all('api/people/').getList().then(response => {
    this.test = response;
    console.log(response);
 });
}
```

I have the following configurations defined in my app.js file

```
 .config(/*@ngInject*/function(RestangularProvider) {
  RestangularProvider.setBaseUrl('http://localhost:8080/');
RestangularProvider.setFullResponse(true);
RestangularProvider.addResponseInterceptor(function(data, operation, what, url, response, deferred) {
    var extractedData;
    if (operation === "getList") {
      extractedData = data.result;
    } else {
      extractedData = data;
    }
    return extractedData;
  });
})
```

**Console**

[image: Console]

**Network**

[image: Network]

Comment: What if you do not add Response Interceptor?

Comment: I get the below error if I remove response interceptor, angular.min.js:107 Error: Response for getList SHOULD be an array and not an object or something else
    at q (restangular.min.js:6)
    at angular.min.js:118
    at n.$eval (angular.min.js:133)
    at n.$digest (angular.min.js:130)
    at n.$apply (angular.min.js:133)
    at g (angular.min.js:87)
    at K (angular.min.js:91)
    at XMLHttpRequest.A.onload (angular.min.js:92)

Comment: O.k. But are you sure response from Restangular `getList()` is in `data.result` ?

Comment: It was data.content and not data.result! Thanks a lot! I'm able to access the array in console now! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be sure the response from Restangular `getList()` is in `data.result` and not in some other `data` property...