# Restangular getList returns empty data

Tags: angularjs, restangular

I've looked extensively at some answers provided to similar questions, and I am aware that there is some interesting stuff going on with promises and unwrapping thereof, which is also documented on the restangular project, but I can not in any way get this call to return any data.

My controller:

```
angular.module('newClientApp')
 .controller('BeerCtrl', function ($scope, Beer) {    

  Beer.getList().then(function(data) {
    $scope.beers = data;
    console.log("resp:" + $scope.beers);
 });
});
```

I've also tried this variant in the controller because the above returns absolutely nothing not even undefined:

```
$scope.beers = Beer.getList().$object;
  console.log($scope.beers);
```

which returns [], and this beast of an object that starts out with the following output but lists all the other methods of Restangular as well: (Is my data in there somewhere?)

```
addRestangularMethod:function addRestangularMethodFunction(name, operation, path, defaultParams,     defaultHeaders, defaultElem)
all:function all(parent, route) 
.... and on and on and on
```

My main module:

```
angular
  .module('newClientApp', [
    'ngRoute',
    'restangular'
])
.config(function ($routeProvider, RestangularProvider) {

RestangularProvider.setBaseUrl('http://localhost:8080');

$routeProvider

  .when('/beer', {
    templateUrl: 'views/beer.html',
    controller: 'BeerCtrl',
    controllerAs: 'beer'
  })
  .otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/'
  })
})
.factory('BeerRestangular', function(Restangular) {
  return Restangular.withConfig(function(RestangularConfigurer) {
    RestangularConfigurer.setRestangularFields({
      id: '_id'
    });
 });
})
.factory('Beer', function(BeerRestangular){
   return BeerRestangular.service('beer') // The actual api resource from whence it pulls
});
```

I'v tried changing the return on the factory from .service to .all, but no effect.

I'v tried this suggestion, and added the interceptor, but it too returned a data array of 0. [Restangular getList() returning empty array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39392613/restangular-getlist-returning-empty-array)

I've been using postman to access my api, so I know that it returns valid information.  I've read though this but it's not helping. https://github.com/mgonto/restangular#how-do-i-handle-crud-operations-in-a-list-returned-by-restangular.

Can anyone please help me get at the data, I'll repay you with internet points :D, and eternal gratitude.

I've also tried without success to use $resource and $http, but those are other problems.

of note my main dependencies look like this:

```
"dependencies": {
"angular": "^1.4.0",
"bootstrap": "^3.2.0",
"angular-route": "^1.4.0",
"restangular": "^1.5.2"
```

Comment: "I've also tried without success to use $resource and $http, but those are other problems.".  That implies that either there is something wrong with your API, or that there is some common thread between the 3 methods that you are doing wrong each time.  Perhaps listing (briefly) the issues you have with the other methods might help narrow this down some.

Comment: Also, In adding that interceptor right into the main module, I'll get this back:
Object {data: Array[0], status: 200, config: Object, statusText: "OK"}

Comment: @Claies. Yes I thought so too, but Like I said in using Postman (great tool btw), it's just fine, Also I can post, put and delete to the same api, just not get.

Comment: I didn't get to far using the $http service. It consistently prepends my local url to the url I'm trying to access so it's doing something like. http://localhost:9000/localhost:8080/beer   i.e. no bueno.

Comment: that means you left out the protocol in your url value. Go to your browser address bar and copy a url and paste it in editor...will see it has a protocol in it

Comment: I just ran another test, and indeed it looks like there is something wrong with the output, possibly header based. If in my api I use 

    res.send([{some json stuff in here}])   It works. 

So my question becomes related to node-restful, and why its mucking up the response.